# Stub Methods with Block Arguments

Tags: objective-c-blocks, ocmock

I'm trying to stub a method which has got an block argument.

```
[[[myMock stub] andCall:@selector(performBlock:) onObject:self] performBlock:[OCMArg any]];
```

The block is of a simple type.

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)(void);
```

Upon execution I get the following error:

```
unexpected method invoked: performBlock:<__NSStackBlock__: 0xbffff418>
                  stubbed: performBlock:<OCMAnyConstraint: 0x1c1ff70>
```

It seems as a block argument is not compatible with `[OCMArg any]`. Any tipps how to stub this method then?

Comment: Stubbing definitely works with block arguments and `[OCMock any]`. Can you post a bit more of your test case?

Comment: Thanks for trying out. I thought I have catched the problem, but it must lie elsewhere then. I'll post more when I'm working on it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have cropped too much from my example.
I had a second parameter of type `bool` which is not compatible with `[OCMArg any]`.

Even worse: You don't get a compiler warning for it unless you use `BOOL` instead...